# MongoDB query an array for an exact element match, but may be out of order

Tags: mongoid, mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
{ users: ["2", "3", "4"] }
```

I'm try to query this document by matching the users array.

```
db.things.find( { users: { $all: [ "2", "3", "4" ] } } )
```

That query works, but would also return this document:

```
{ users: ["2", "3", "4", "5"] }
```

Last requirement is to be able to query the users array with the elements out of order, say `[ "3", "4", "2" ]` in the query, and it be able to return my first document listed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

I'm also using mongoid, if that has a helper that anyone knows about, but can do a straight mongo query if I need to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could combine your query with a { users : { $size : 3 } } clause and adjust the size to match the number of users you are querying for.  That would ensure that you are getting the exact set, and not a subset.

If the elements are out of order, you might need to do a { users : { $exists : "1" } } for each, and combine those and the $size clause all together.

Comment: Great! non-trivial logic for relational brains ) I just didn't understand about `$exists` - why do we need it?

Comment: Because the $all may not (note, I have not tested it) return a document if the elements are out of order.

Comment: How would you ensure the array order so that no documents are returned out of order?

Comment: I tested the $all operator , and I found that it does return the non ordered arrays as well, means, that the document { users: ["2", "3", "4"] } will match the query:{"users" : { "$all" : [ "3" , "4" , "2"]}}. I have requirement to get the documents that stands for the order as well, means, that only the next criteria : {"users" : { "$all" : [ "2" , "3" , "4"]}} will return a result. Does anybody know how to achieve it?

Comment: { users: {"$all": [3, 1, 2]}} with { users: {"$size": 3}} operator worked nicely! Nice tip, @ChrisShain!

Answer (score -1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165121/mongodb-query-an-array-for-an-exact-element-match-but-may-be-out-of-order/6165143#6165143) is incorrect.

to query a document for exactly matches in an array do this.

`db.things.insert({a:[1,2]});`

`db.things.insert({a:[1,2,3]});`

`db.things.find({a:[1,2]});`

`returns {a:[1,2]}`

Hope this helps - it's so obvious that it's not in the docs

Comment: Which answer? Answers on StackOverflow do not have to appear in the order they are posted. If you claim that someone else's answer that was accepted and commented by the original poster as working is incorrect, you must be a little more constructive in explaining why the solution offered is not the best.

Comment: That answer requires the array to be in the same order. $all+$size doesn't require the order to be the same.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get all of documents that contains an ordered subset? Means, in case that I query for [1,2] I want it to result with [1,2], [1,2,3] but if I have [1,3,2] record I don't want it to be part of the result, since it doesn't contain [1,2].